# how to select the records from table when table name is sent as a parameter to a ms sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want a function which will return me all the records in a particular table  .
The input parameter of the function will be table name .

can anyone help me out ?

Comment: You should give us more info but in general it is something like this. 'select * from' . $table

Comment: i need a function . input parameter is table name which is a string . I need the output as all records of that table . I cant do direct select * since the table name what i send is a string

Comment: @NitheshKumarKuntady I posted an answer, but can you explain your requirement? What do you need such function for? What can you simple execute queries with appropriate table name?

Comment: @NitheshKumarKuntady It's a terrible idea. Don't do it.

Comment: You have one of a number of problems with your setup - you either have multiple tables with the same structure (which suggests that they probably ought to be the same table), or you're using `select *` (which means you're making the server do more work than it ought to, and retrieving more data than is required).

Answer (score 4):

You need to build your query dynamically. Have a look at [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for more info.

```
declare @TableName sysname = 'TableName'
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * from '+quotename(@TableName)
exec (@sql)
```

As a stored procedure it would look like this:

```
create procedure GetAll
  @TableName sysname
as

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * from '+quotename(@TableName)
exec (@sql)
```

And as [Rashmi Kant Shrivastwa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053331/rashmi-kant-shrivastwa) pointed out in a comment, you can not use dynamic SQL in user defined functions.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use dynamic sql query inside function. for your desired result you may take help of 
**sql-CLR function**

you may check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/TableValuedFnsAsArrays.aspx)  or [this one](http://sqlx.blogspot.com/2009/06/run-dynamic-t-sql-statement-from.html) it may help you